# Analytic Hierarchy Process (AHP) - factor weight score

Tags: multilevel-analysis, factor-analysis, scales, weighted-mean

As title mentioned, how to determine the 'scale of relative importance' point for factor weight score?

Besides, I have read some example of ahp saying there are 1-9 point, 1-5 point (1,2,3,4,5) and even 1-5 point (1,3,5) for scale of relative importance point. How do I decide which one to adopt? I have 10 criteria for structural building system selection. I have set a questionnaire with likert scale for respondent to rate the criteria.

Thank you!

Comment: a reproducible example or some links to resources (e.g., definitions of concepts) would help

Comment: You should fill in the pair wise comparison matrix and compute the dominant eigenvector?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently reading about AHP. Saaty, the creator of AHP, promotes the scale 1-9 as the best. Other studies like [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212567114003323) from Franek and Kresta in 2014 analyze other options but they still conclude that the 1-9 scale is a "favorable" option. I would try with that scale. Nevertheless it is known that the AHP method loose effectiveness if more than 9 criteria are pairwise compared. I would suggest to organize your criteria as a hierarchy to make the whole process easier and more consistent. Preferently don't compare more than 5 criteria at the same time.

Apparently you already have a normalized scale to measure the criteria. Applying AHP should be a piece of cake.

EDIT:
If the Likert scale is an ordinal scale it doesn't support relevant math operations like + and * of AHP. You will need to measure differently (using a ratio scale) if you expect to obtain general scores for your alternatives.